# How to fuse values from 2 separate columns into a common column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Is there a simple way to fuse values from two separate (albeit similar) columns in PostgreSQL?

For example, the following statement:

```
SELECT a, b FROM stuff;
```

would currently result in:

```
a         b
-----------
1         2
1         3
1         4
```

However, I'd like to have the two columns fused in the following way:

```
ab
---
1
1
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to get 2 results from same complex query without losing performance try something like:

```
WITH source AS 
(SELECT A,B
 FROM your_complex_query)
SELECT A as AB
FROM source 
UNION ALL
SELECT B as AB
FROM source
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select a as ab from stuff
union all 
select b from stuff
order by 1
```

Comment: This works, but it is 70% slower than "SELECT a, b from stuff".  In my case, "stuff" is a very complicated query.   Is there a faster way?

Comment: What does *complicated* mean? Complicated query, long running? Consider adding the query to your question.

Comment: Try losing the "order by" - does that help?

Comment: Dropping the `order by` clause might speed it up a little. But the real speed-up would be storing all that data in a single column to begin with. (That might not be practical, though.)